# Update records from one workbook to another in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I would like to know if it is possible to update a workbook(wb1) using the records on another workbook(wb2).

Scenario:

wb2 is a workbook that is being send to us from another office branch. It contains all their inventory.

wb1 is a workbook here on our main office. It should contain all inventory of the main office, as well as the office branch.

My problem is that, there's already an existing records for the other branch inside the wb1. I would like to know if it is possible to use macro or vba to automatically copy the content inside the wb2, and paste it to wb1 without duplicating what's already there. I've tried

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\myworkbook.xls")

Dim x As Variant
x = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MyRange").Value

thisworkbook.sheets("wb1").range("MyRange").value = x
```

I'm stuck, because my records are being duplicated and not updated. So now, what I do manually delete the current records in my wb1, then paste the updated record on wb2. Manually as well.

Comment: When you say record, what are we talking about? In a DB (database) a record is a single row (first, last, phone, address, mail, etc...). And if you are using "records", then you should have (must have) a unique identifier. That is the solution. If you have several workbooks, then each workbook needs to be set up exacltly the same way and have a unique ID. For example, if you don't have unique ID's you could create one, and have a unique code built into the unique ID (e.g. TX-Houston=2310, CA-SanDiego=1100, CA-SanDiego-92020=1120). Then you could use the `delete duplicates` WRT unique ID's.

Comment: An alternative to my comment above is this. Iv'e used this method before. Use a workbook that is shared on a server. Excel knows when it is being used by several people at the same time and will make adjustments for you.

Comment: @ejbytes, thanks for your response. When I say record, I'm talking about a record inside my table on my sheet. I do not have any kind of database (access,sql,etc.), as the table on my sheet itself serves as the database. And also, all tables from all workbooks are the same structure (columns, column name, etc.) and yes they have one unique identifier, which is called EMN (Equipment Management Number. First Column). Also, I do not know the "Delete Duplicates WRT". Sorry. Also, shared workbook is not possible, the other branch does not have an internet connection.

Comment: There is a delete duplicates function built into Excel with respect to unique identifiers. Select your data that needs to check for duplicates, Data Tab, Data Tools group, Delete Duplicates. I'm sure if you "record procedures as a Macro", you could figure out a nice way to add that to your existing VB code.

Comment: Because Excel is not a Database, it will get quite manual if you must have several workbooks to work from. You have to maintain them manually because worksheet are not databases and they don't function like one. I'd suggest converting to using "tables" instead of "worksheets", in an MS Access database. Here is a link how to manually merge Excel sheets: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/3-ways-merge-de-duplicate-excel-files-martin-judd